# Macbook shuts down when battery is empty (should have went to sleep)

Tags: macbook, sleep, battery, shutdown

In the past few weeks, my macbook shuts down when the battery dies. The battery does not even die at 0%, sometimes it shuts down at 5% or 10% remaining. I tried calibrating the baterry following this website: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1490. But it does not really help. I regularly use battery in my macbook, I'd say I use around 2-3 cycles a week.

My charge cycles is 440 cycles, and my current battery capacity is 3400mAh from the original 4100mAh. I have 2008 unibody Macbook. Does anyone know how to make it goes to sleep before the battery's dead?

EDIT:

The OS seems the think that the battery is ok...

[image]

Comment: It may be time for a new battery. If the calibration didn't work, then logic dictates the software will not be able to detect the battery state, in order to prevent data loss, by going to sleep.

Comment: Hmmm the OS doesn't seem to think so though. I attached a screnshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long have you had your battery? I found that, depending on how hard your CPU works your battery, the lifespan of a battery can be as short as 18-24 months, with decreases in capacity as quickly as 1 year.

(NOTE: This is *not* normal, in the case of the Macbook I am talking about, it was stuck running a lot of CPU hogging Java and Flash environments. It also was fully charged and discharged 2-3 times per day, 5 days a week.)

But I have seen my system, when the CPU is getting pounded, going from 20% to losing power (and failing to sleep) on my older, extremely over-used battery.

I have a white Macbook, in case you wonder what battery I am using.

Comment: Had it for almost 3 years. I'm aware it has around 2 years of lifespan. I guess I'll keep using this laptop for a little more then just replace it with a new one later...

Comment: Yeah. I don't know if its possible, but I'd like the OS to log the battery level periodically, and then on reboot compare the last logged level to the output of "last", to see if the threshold needs to be increased to avoid brownout.

Comment: You can use coconut battery for the logging, but I don't think the OS can prevent brownout.